# Compile iOS strings files from command line

Tags: iphone, ios

Compiled iOS apps have localized strings files compiled into binary PList files and they are converted by Xcode.

Is there any way to compile them from command line from the original strings files?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. What do you have as input? What do you want as output? Please clarify!

Comment: the Build Rule that handles string files is "CopyStringsFile". looking at the build output, it calls an internal Xcode function called "builtin-copyStrings". as far as i know, this isn't available outside of xcode. you could experiment with the shell tool "plutil" which, amongst other things, can convert a .plist to a binary representation.

Answer (score 5):

I think I found what I was looking for:

```
plutil -convert binary1 Localizable.strings
```

Answer (score 3):

`plutil` it is.

The build task is here `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/CopyStringsFile.xcspec`

It runs `copystrings` ruby script, which is based on `iconv` and `plutil`